# how to get data mysql from post view to controller | Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, xml

This is part of function controller:

```
    public function generate_google_post()
        {
$query = $this->sitemap_model->get_all_products();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
            $xml .= '<item>
                <g:id>'.$row['id'].'</g:id>
    </item>';
    }
        echo $xml;
        }
```

From `view.php` In above function I  can submit to controller and generate correct XML file with data from mysql.

**Issue start from here:**

now I want do some customization to **write xml content directly in storefront (view)** and then call input data to controller and generate xml.

For this I try:

```
public function generate_google_post2()
    {

    $xml   = '<channel>';
    $query = $this->sitemap_model->get_all_products();

    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $xml .= $this->input->post('add-list');
    }

    $xml .= '</channel>';

    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');

    echo $xml;
    }
}
```

and in view page I try:

```
<?php echo form_open('sitemap_controller/generate_google_post2'); ?>
            <textarea name="add-list" id="add-list" rows="10" cols="75"> </textarea>
<button type="submit" name="process" value="generate" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo trans('download_feed'); ?></button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?><!-- form end -->
```

and now in storefront text area form I try post:

```
 <item>
 <gid>'.$row['id'].'</gid>
</item>
```

XML file generate sucess but the problem is I get output XML:

```
<channel> <item>
 <gid>'.$row['id'].'</gid>
</item> <item>
 <gid>'.$row['id'].'</gid>
</item> </channel>
```

So missing data from mysql. Is any way post from text are and in this way get data from database and then generate to xml ?

[text area view post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYoag.png)

I try add `if($_POST)` then `$query = $this->sitemap_model->get_all_products();` and

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
        $xml .= $this->input->post('add-list');
    }
```

But this not resolved this issue. Full code:

```
public function generate_google_post2()
    {
  if($_POST){
      $id = $this->input->post('add-list');
      $query = $this->sitemap_model->get_all_products();
      $xml   = '<channel>';
   
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $xml .= $this->input->post('add-list');
    }

    $xml .= '</channel>';

    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');

    echo $xml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$row` variable is being interpreted as text. You wouldn't want to do this anyway as you would be very vulnerable to malicious code submitted in the form. Essentially you are trying to provide some template to the backend to fill with data.

Provide a placeholder in your form.

```
<item><gid>{id}</gid></item>
```

In your foreach loop, replace the placeholder with your data.

```
$template = $this->input->post('add-list');
// Replace your placeholder
$template = str_replace('{id}',            $row['id'], $template);
$template = str_replace('{title}',         $row['title'], $template);
$template = str_replace('{sku}',           $row['sku'], $template);
$template = str_replace('{somethingelse}', $row['thing'], $template);
$xml .= $template;
```

Anyone who uses this form who is not you would need to be instructed what specific text to use as the placeholder. So you would need to know, or control, what placeholders the user enters.

You could control the placeholders on the front end with buttons that insert the text on the cursor. https://jsfiddle.net/xhgk8cz7/1/

Comment: thank you for response. I think now about your solution but the problem is - this is for end customer (admin) and not always the customer (admin) will want to generate a product ID. Example some times we need use only sku and title and some times id and title. And now Should I list all the variables in this situation and add if empty  row then skip?

Comment: @MarcinWierzycki So the end user will be constructing their own XML but may need to insert more than a simple id?

Comment: yes this is correct.  "end user will be constructing their own XML but may need to insert more than a simple id"

Comment: example want to  post <sku>$row['sku']</sku><id>$row['sku']</id> and we need transform this to XML from post.   Output example <products> <product><!-- start customer put this --> <sku>test-sku</sku><id>15</id> <!-- end customer put this --></product></products>

Comment: This is very good solution I think now! But in this case can you please   help me how can I add now more than 2 placeholder?  example:  <id>{id}</id> <sku>{sku}</sku>  <title>{title}</title> and this str_replace to  {id} to $row['id']    {sku} to  $row['sku']  etc.  and the second thig. Now I try test with this one PLACEHOLDER.  But everytime I get output without str replace <item><gid>PLACEHOLDER</gid></item>

Comment: Please see screen attached 1) function https://prnt.sc/Q7wSPAop4lE3   2) Fill Form  https://prnt.sc/F5Ex1_IdUxpz  3) output https://prnt.sc/4h8Thjmv-qJZ

Comment: @MarcinWierzycki See my edits above and the linked fiddle for an example.

Comment: thank you for your update. I check this,  but unfortunately I don't know why it doesn't fetch  data from the database, but instead this still generates in xml  placeholders. This is current output.xml <channel> <item>
<gid>{id}</gid>
<title>{title}</title>
<sku>{title}</sku>
</item>

Comment: Dump the post input before and after the `str_replace()` and see if it doesn't match. It needs to match the text exactly to replace it properly.

Comment: For test please see I  use this function to check if we get correct data from db without post and please see 1) function https://prnt.sc/mYr8Jqksf6Yv 2) correct result output  https://prnt.sc/3ijiSvXmPHZq  but the problem is with str_replace when I post from form with placeholders

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake in my example. You need to reassign `$template`. So you would use `$template = str_replace('{id}', $row['id'], $template);`

Comment: Yes! this is it. Really thank you for your time and such a helpful lesson. Thank you again. Working perfect. Have a nice night.

Comment: I also fallow to your: https://jsfiddle.net/xhgk8cz7/1/  here I created my own base on codeigniter my form https://jsfiddle.net/d3qxLjao/  and here working. But the problem is in my codeigniter not working. When I click on button then not add in text area. I use  library for text area https://gist.github.com/sente/1083506 for  textarea xml syntax highlighting. Do you think this library may cause this issue with no reaction on button click ?

Comment: @MarcinWierzycki Hard to say without seeing the whole thing. The fiddle you posted does not include the gist you linked so I can't see how you expect it to work.

Comment: currently I include gist. Can you please check here? https://jsfiddle.net/nyh2zjbq/1/   (also - by the way are you working with codeigniter under paid task? ( we need small help in our  project)

Comment: also with your solition, do you think is any way post <g:id>{id}</g:id> ? Because when I include in tag ":"  then I get output <g>1</g>

Comment: Looking at your updated fiddle, it looks like that gist script converts the textarea content into separate divs. The placeholder insert function only works on text areas so it would not work here. I would not know how to implement something similar without some more research.


No, I am not working with codeigniter and unfortunately cannot provide help.


I am not sure what you mean by your last comment. Is your desired output `<g:id>1</g:id>`?

Comment: ok thank you for reply. with this second ,  when I post  from textarea <g:id>{id}</g:id>  to controller  then I get output in xml <g>15</g>   so the problem is when I post tag with ":"  because then script "truncate" all after ";" and get output <g>15</g> instand of <g:id>15</g:id>

Comment: What does your controller look like? Are you saying the gist you are using for syntax highlighting is stripping the `:id` or is it a problem with your own code?